# How to install only nvcc inside an nvidia/cuda base docker?

Tags: nvcc, nvidia-docker

We use pytorch in a `nvidia/cuda:xx.x-base-ubuntu18.04` (**base**) image with a final size of ~6 GB.

I know that `nvcc` is available in `nvidia/cuda:xx.x-devel` (**devel**) tag, but it increases the image size to > 10 GB.

Can I install `nvcc` only in the base image?

Answer (score 0):

nividia provided installers have command line options.
this will allow to install selected components. (such as with or without graphics drivers, samples, docs, ...)

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example related to nvcc?

Comment: linux run-file installer: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-advanced